# sql with where - in php

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

I have an SQL query that works,
and inside the loop I want a call to another SQL query which I expect only one result, but I get an error.

Here is the code:

```
$i = 0;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `orders` ORDER BY `ID` ASC ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
    $i++;
    $productResult = mysql_select_db("SELECT * FROM `page` WHERE 'id'=".$i."'");
}
```

And here is what is want to get from this code:

```
<?=$productResult['title'];?>
```

How can I fix it?
I know the problem is in this line:

```
mysql_select_db("SELECT * FROM `page` WHERE 'id'=".$i."'");
```

Comment: Learn to use prepared statements with MySQLi or PDO. The MySQL library is deprecated

Comment: also this `<?=$productResult['title'];?>` makes no sense if you want to print information use  `echo` or `print` or if you want to manipulate use it where you want

Comment: i am really afraid it there will be thousand of rows ... it mean thousand of queries if you are showing result like so shows question use pagination or something like that and use `limit` or anything else to control query and eliminate query from loop

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove the single quotes around `id` - if you want to quote a table/column name in MySQL you need to use backticks. However, there's no reason to do so unless you use a name that is a reserved keyword.

You also need to replace `mysql_select_db` with `mysql_query`.

Last but not least, sending queries within a loop is a bad idea and you forgot to actually retrieve your results.

And finally, since you appear to have no PHP/MySQL knowledge at all yet, here's a suggestion that you should *really* follow:
[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Using my comment as a rep catalyst are we? :P

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `page` WHERE `id`=".$i);
```

I'd recommend to use `PDO` or `MySqli` since  `MySql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: all `mysql_*` function are deprecated not only `mysql_query` :)